# Prevent Authentication popup 401 with CouchDB PouchDB

Tags: javascript, authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

For a JavaScript web app (AngularJS based) I am using PouchDB replicating a CouchDB database on my server.
Authentication in PouchDB works nicely with [pouchdb-authentication](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication/). I want to manage this through a html/js login screen.

However, if the user enters wrong credentials, I receive a `401 Unauthorized` from the CouchDB server that causes a browser popup asking for credentials.

How can I prevent this ugly Authentication popup and just handle everything from my javascript?!

Comment: would you mind marking one of the answers as accepted solution?

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the solution:

Edit the CouchDB config `local.ini` and change the HTTP Header sent in response:

```
WWW-Authenticate = Other realm="app"
```

Originally this is

```
WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"
```

or if it is commented, that's what is sent out anyway. The `WWW-Authenticate = Basic` apparently causes the browser to handle (failed) authentication by showing its modal. Changing `Basic` to anything else makes the browser ignore it and you can deal with the login yourself.

Comment: Although this doesn't cause the modal to show up, you can't login to [fauxton](http://couchdb.apache.org/fauxton-visual-guide/) anymore, it seems.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I also had problems using futon with those changes. After logging in on my own app, I was also authenticated for Futon however

Answer (score 4):

#### Update 2015.12.18

After a lot of testing I arrived at the second solution outlined. All you need to do is install nginx with the headers-more-module. Add the following to your nginx-config:

```
location / {

    # forward all request headers to backend
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    # these settings come from the CouchDB wiki
    proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # your CouchDB backend
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5984;

    # replace WWW-Authenticate header in response if authorization failed
    more_set_headers -s 401 'WWW-Authenticate: Other realm="App"';
}

# location to handle access to Futon
location /_utils/ {

    # forward all request headers to backend
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    # these settings come from the CouchDB wiki
    proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # your CouchDB backend
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5984;

    # DO NOT replace WWW-Authenticate header in response if authorization failed
    # more_set_headers -s 401 'WWW-Authenticate: Other realm="App"';

    # Handle redirects
    proxy_redirect default;
}
```

And your are set. You can continue using pouchdb-authentication or write your own login handler.

#### Original Post

Sorry to answer, but I cannot comment (yet).

I suffer from the same problem, even worse that on OS X the WWW-Authenticate parameter is lower-cased on every restart of CouchDB and therefore not recognized any more. Therefore it has to be set after EACH restart using Futon/Fauxton or the API.

You could try and play with the next parameter (see http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/server/authn.html). In principle you send your auth-request to (example in angular2):

```js
// assuming you bootstrapped HTTP_PROVIDERS and injected Http

// configure headers
let headers: Headers = new Headers()
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json')
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password))

// using the injected Http instance
this.http
// post to _session specifying next and the redirect
.post(
  'http://localhost:5984/_session?next=/successfullyLoggedInPage'
  , JSON.stringify({'name': username, 'password': password})
  , {headers: headers}
)
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.subscribe(
  (res) => {
    // successful auth
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err.status === 401) // failed auth
  }
)
```

In my setup the web-app and CouchDB are served from two different origins. I can only get this working if I disable web-security in Chrome due to cross-origin restrictions. I believe a reverse proxy could rewrite the redirect response, e. g. using nginx's proxy_redirect (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

I believe the best solution is to modify the response headers by a reverse proxy. For nginx there is a module called ngx_headers_more (see https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#readme) which should be able to do this. One could check for 401 responses and then modify the header from Authentication: Basic to Authentication: Other, therefore disabling the modal. In principle Futon/Fauxton should still work then, no? I haven't tried this approach yet but in the location block of nginx you need to specify

```
more_set_headers -s 401 'WWW-Authenticate: Other realm="App"'
```

I hope someone more qualified can add his/her two cents.

Answer (score 1):

I was having more or less the same problem. Though I am using a reverse proxy with the 'proxy' authentication handler of CouchDB. When the user tries to do something that he is not allowed to (creating a DB while he is not an admin), a 401 response was returned by CouchDB, triggering HTTP basic auth. Not so nice, as the reverse proxy handles authentication based on X509 client certificates. I actually think that CouchDB should return a 403 response, but that's a different discussion.

To fix it, I used your answers, but I am not so eager to use an external Nginx module (ngx_headers_more) and actually am not so fond of changing the header to a 'nonsense' value. Instead, with the existing proxy module in Nginx, you can just remove the WWW-Authenticate all together:

```
proxy_pass              http://${COUCHDB_HOSTNAME}:${COUCHDB_PORT};
proxy_hide_header       WWW-Authenticate;
```

Seems to be working fine. See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header for its documentation.