# How do i remove the authentication modal in pouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I'm having a big Problem. Whenever I'm connecting to Cloudant via PouchDB a nasty modal pops up that asks for authentication. I'm using PouchDB's [authentication Plugin](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) and the [responsible command](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication#pouchdb-setup-1) for this NOT TO HAPPEN. But somehow it still does. The modal keeps popping up, no matter what I do. It shuts down my whole production and I've been trying to solve this for days now.

I have an [example](https://github.com/Java-Jonas/-skipSetup-true-not-working) on GitHub.

Help is very appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am getting the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename ["Basic" in the WWW-Authenticate header](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/http.html?highlight=realm#httpd/WWW-Authenticate) your server sends to something the browser is not hard-coded to recognize and react to. I know nothing about cloudant, but it looks like their docs route back to couchdb for manual configuration so hopefully they have identical configuration for this.

For couchDB, changing the `Basic` to `Basicfoo` suppresses the browser authentication windows when pouchdb hits the URL with Authentication.

(You can also look for other solutions particular to your DB and any proxies you might be using now that you know you want to change Basic in the WWW-Authenticate header, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32670580/1269466) has a solution for nginx.)

Comment: I kinda know this is the right answer, as it has worked for other people. But somehow not for me :/ . Changing "Basic" to something else didn't help. The Modal keeps showing up.

Comment: @JonasBergner if I point my browser directly to the db reference in your example I get: `WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Cloudant Private Database"` in the 401 and therefore a popup, one way or another you need to change the Basic, though it might only be possible through reverse proxying if their cloud service isn't fully configurable..

Comment: @JonasBergner: does the modal show every time or only if you enter the wrong credentials?

Comment: @TylerDurden always. I'm now trying to put a proxy inbetween and handle the authentication server-side. That should allow me to suppress the modal. :) hopefully...